# Why won't the loop take any keystroke to stop?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create an infinite loop of a circle moving across the screen using a while statement, and I would like to know how to use a key stroke to activate a break command to stop the loop?

```
while run_me:
    clock.tick(fps_limit) 

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run_me = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                T = 1
                while T == 1:
                    posx = posx - 1
                    screen.fill(black)
                    pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorcircle, (posx, posy), 50)
                    pygame.display.flip()
                    if posx == 0:
                        posx = posx + 600
```

Comment: `T` doesn't change in the while loop, so it will never stop. You should separate event and rendering logic.

Comment: yeah I managed to make another code that worked without using 2 loops, I even managed to make it so that it can go in all directions.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the endless inner loop. Once this loop is entered, it is never terminated. Never implement a game loop in the main application loop. Use the main application loop and use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to implement a continuous movement.

```py
while run_me:
    clock.tick(fps_limit) 

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run_me = False
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:    
        posx = posx - 1
        if posx == 0:
            posx = posx + 600
    
    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorcircle, (posx, posy), 50)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to have two loops. Currently you don't do any event handling inside your inner loop, which means there's no good way to stop it. But rather than adding additional `pygame.event` stuff in there, why not just reuse the code from the main loop?

Here's code that is probably pretty close to working (it's incomplete, so I've not tested it). Most of the changes are just unindenting the stuff you already had.

```
while run_me:
    clock.tick(fps_limit) 

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run_me = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                T = 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:   # add some code to stop drawing
                T = 0

    if T == 1:               # change this to an `if` rather than a `while`, and unindent
        posx = posx - 1
        screen.fill(black)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorcircle, (posx, posy), 50)
        pygame.display.flip()
        if posx == 0:
            posx = posx + 600
```

You should probably use a better variable name than `T`.